# debbuging a plug-in DLL

Tags: debugging, dll, windows-7-x64

I am working on a plug-in for an application. I have old development tools that have problems. My development tools are all from old 32 bit versions. CodeWarrior 6.7.and 8. I am running windows 7 pro 64 bit and having problems with the old tools. The CodeWarrior debugger will only work one time and I have to reboot before it will work again. It also has some problem using it. Break points stop working.

I switched to UeStudio from IDM but can not get a debugger to work. I created a project to use the compilers from Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0. UeStudio is supposed to use an integrated debugger. It downloads WinDbg.exe but it wont start up. The only WinDbg I found on Microsoft is from the Debugging Tools for Windows (x86) and (x64). It does not integrate with UeStudio. It starts up in a separate window. I have played around with it a bit but can not get it to load my DLL. I keep getting and error that it can not load my symbols (mismatching symbol file). I have set it to look were the '.pdb' for my plugin is located an doubled checked that it is correct. It's message names my DLL. I do not have symbols for the application. They do not supply one. I can load my source file and set Break points. But can not examine data.

Anybody get UeStudio debugging to work on windows 7? Or have any idea on debugging DLL on windows 7 cheaply.

Answer (score 1):

I use OllyDebug.
[OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de)

IDA is also very nice (paid)